# Реализация и использование Identity функции

Tags: c++, функциональное-программирование

Хотел бы начать с примера, поэтому для начала опишу несколько используемых функций.

Тривиальная функция для композиции других функций:

```
template<typename R1, typename ...Args, typename R2>
decltype(auto) compose(std::function<R2(R1)> g, std::function<R1(Args...)> f)
{
    return [=](Args... arg) { return g(f(arg...)); };
}
```

Перегруженный оператор << (для удобства):

```
template<typename R1, typename ...Args, typename R2>
decltype(auto) operator << (std::function<R2(R1)> g, std::function<R1(Args...)> f)
{
    return compose(g, f);
}
```

Вспомогательная функция для создания экземпляра `std::function` из указателя на функцию:

```
template<typename R, typename ...Args>
decltype(auto) make_function(R(*f)(Args...))
{
    return std::function<R(Args...)>(f);
}
```

[Identity](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:id) функция:

```
template<typename T>
decltype(auto) identity(T&& arg)
{
    return std::forward<T>(arg);
}
```

Собственно, пример:

```
int f(char c);
double g(int i);

int main()
{
    auto r1 = make_function(g) << make_function(f);
    auto r2 = make_function(f) << /* ? (здесь нужно использовать Id(char)) */;

    std::cout << typeid(r1).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(r2).name() << std::endl;
}
```

Получить композицию функций f и g не составило труда, а вот композицию f и identity(char) - здесь мне не понятно, как я могу использовать функцию identity, ведь она шаблонная и я не могу получить указатель на нее, соответственно, не могу получить необходимый экземпляр `std::function`.

**UPD0**: вариант с лямбда-функцией

Если использовать предложенную @HolyBlackCat реализацию identity:

```
auto identity = [](auto &&arg) -> decltype(auto) { return decltype(arg)(arg); };
```

и дополнительно перегрузить функцию compose:

```
template<typename R1, typename ...Args, typename F>
decltype(auto) compose(std::function<R1(Args...)> f, F id)
{
    return [=](Args... arg) { return f(id(std::move(arg...))); };
}
```

становится возможным использование последней следующим образом:

```
compose(make_function(f), identity);
```

Comment: Тут нужная простая вспомогательная функция для identity, которая будет принимать параметр и делать что-то такое `template <typename T> decltype(auto) indentity_helper(T&&) { return static_cast<T (*)(T)>(&identity<T>); }` Что-то более универсальное c++ дать не может пока. Можно и без `static_cast` кстати. Если хотите функциональное программирование, то лучше смотреть в сторону boost phoenix.

Comment: *"Тривиальная функция"* - месье шутник... А почему бы не получить указатель на конкретный вариант шаблонной функции? `&identity<char>`

Comment: @MrBin, а мы можем подобным образом брать адрес функции - &idenity<T>? И еще, на мой взгляд, эта функция не должна принимать параметр. Собственно, если убрать его из Вашего примера - ничего страшного не произойдет.

Comment: @VTT, ну нет, я тут без иронии говорил :) Я к тому, что тут ф-ия g принимает только один аргумент. А что касается Вашего вопроса, собственно, я уже спросил у MrBin'а на счет этого - признаюсь, я не знал что так можно делать (если можно).

Comment: Конечно можно убрать. Но раз уж функциональное программирование то лучше делать так:`identity(value)` чем `identity<decltype(value)>()`. В данном случае различие только написании, но читается первое быстрее и понятнее по моему мнению.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, тут только что был Ваш комментарий, куда дели ? :)

Comment: @MrBin, дело в том, что на момент вызова никакого value нет.

Comment: В моем варианте вы можете создавать identity и через передачу шаблонного параметра, так и через выводимый тип переданного объекта.

Comment: @MrBin, извините, возможно я что-то делаю не так, но пока этот вариант не работает: https://wandbox.org/permlink/3PaMzLRhZx7iDNYq

Comment: Все так, это я переборщил. Можете убирать параметр.

Comment: @MrBin, в примере, ссылку на который я Вас скинул, его уже нет. Но по прежнему не работает. Можете сами запустить и посмотреть. Опять же, я извиняюсь, если что-то не работает по моей глупости.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/j3tJBp

Comment: @MrBin, так - работает :) Спасибо. Вы можете вынести в ответ, я приму.

Comment: Не стоит, это не тянет на полноценный ответ, так как по моему мнению является костылем.

Comment: @MrBin, ну, в том плане, что нужно использовать вспомогательную функцию - да, немного не удобно. Но в целом - решение рабочее. Если Вам интересно, я обновил пост - добавил вариант с использованием лямбда-функции.